# Spark createTableColumnTypes Not Resulting in user supplied schema

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc

Not sure why this isn't working but I'm just trying to apply the below but still getting spark's version of the schema for the table (mysql) containing `text` instead of varchar(128) I'm trying to specify. Trying to just create custom datatypes for my columns with jdbc write. Trying with spark 2.1.0:

```
  def df2DB(
    df: DataFrame,
    batchSize: Int,
    numPartitions: Int,
    database: String,
    table: String): Unit = {

    val mdb = new MetadataBuilder()
    mdb.putString("col1", "INT")
    mdb.putString("col2", "VARCHAR(128)")
    mdb.putString("col3", "VARCHAR(128)")
    val createTableColTypes = mdb.build().json

    df.write.format("jdbc")
      .option("createTableColumnTypes", createTableColTypes)
      .option("url", url)
      .option("dbtable", s"${database}.${table}")
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", pass)
      .option("driver", driver)
      .option("batchsize", batchSize)
      .option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
      .save()
  }
```

I also tried this format without success:

```
df.write.format("jdbc")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .option("url", url)
  .option("dbtable", s"${database}.${table}")
  .option("user", user)
  .option("password", pass)
  .option("driver", driver)
  .option("batchsize", batchSize)
  .option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
  .option("createTableColumnTypes", "COL1 INT, COL2 VARCHAR(128)" )
  .save()
```

Also even when I try using `createTableOptions` like this I'm getting a sql syntax error. I'm not finding any good examples of using these options either together or separately:

```
.option("createTableOptions", "CREATE TABLE tbl1 (col1 int, col2 VARCHAR(128))").save()
```

Comment: Did you resolve this ? I am having a similar issue. I need to enforce writing types.

Comment: This still does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating JSON of your column name to datatype, try using a comma separated list of column name with data type something like this:

```
def df2DB(
    df: DataFrame,
    batchSize: Int,
    numPartitions: Int,
    database: String,
    table: String): Unit = {

    df.write.format("jdbc")
      .option("createTableColumnTypes", "col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(128), col3 VARCHAR(128)")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("dbtable", s"${database}.${table}")
      .option("user", user)
      .option("password", pass)
      .option("driver", driver)
      .option("batchsize", batchSize)
      .option("numPartitions", numPartitions)
      .save()
  }
```

Reference: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/aa4cf2b19e4cf5588af7e2192e0e9f687cd84bc5/examples/src/main/python/sql/datasource.py#L210

Comment: thanks. tried that too but no luck. Still getting int and text in database after writing. I also thought that using MetadataBuilder() was the right way to create a Json to use for this. Am I supposed to tweak the MySqlDialect and customize it to make this work? I thought I could just use these properties in the jdbc write and it would get correctly mapped to DB.

Comment: should i mention all columns or just columns i want to force schema to ?

Comment: @a-herch, might be a bit late for you, but since I was looking for the same today, I looked through Spark code and [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1d2159f888139e65c80db2003d521b0f684df83a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L806-L807) it looks like just columns to force schema it enough.